# PHP table: Array not divisible by 3 not showing last row

Tags: php, html-table

I'm trying to split my array into 3 columns and the remaining that is not divisible by 3 to show as well. Currently it's not displaying. My code as below:

**Count value is 8.**

```
for($i=0; $i < count($subscriber); $i++) {

    if($i%3==0) $middle_data .= '<tr>';

    <td>Array fields goes here</td>

    if(($i+1)%3==0) $middle_data .= '</tr>';
}
```

Currently it shows 2 row but the last row that is not divisible by 3 is not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code echoing all values, but produce invalid markup. It looks like

```
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td>
</table>
```

Try this one

```
$subscriber = array_fill(0, 8, 'value');
$count_column = 3;

// loop by cells count, not values count
$count_cell = ceil(count($subscriber) / $count_column) * $count_column;

$middle_data = "<table>\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_cell; $i++)
    {
    if ($i % $count_column == 0)
        $middle_data .= '<tr>';

    if (isset($subscriber[$i]))
        $middle_data .= '<td>' . $subscriber[$i] . '</td>';
    else
        $middle_data .= '<td></td>';

    if (($i + 1) % $count_column == 0)
        $middle_data .= "</tr>\n";
    }
$middle_data .= "</table>\n";
echo $middle_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   <?php
    $subscriber= array('1','2','3','4','5',6,7,8);
    $middle_data="";

    if(count($subscriber))
    $middle_data .= '<tr>';

    for($i=0; $i < count($subscriber); $i++) 
    {        
        if((($i%3)==0 ) && $i!=0) 
        $middle_data .= '</tr><tr>';
        $middle_data .= " <td>$subscriber[$i] goes here </td>";
    }

    if(count($subscriber))
    $middle_data .= '</tr>';

    echo  $middle_data;
    ?>
```

**output**

```
<tbody><tr> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td></tr> .... </tbody>
```